# concate characters in prolog after spliting the string

Tags: prolog

I want to concate firt letters of two words present in the list.

```
 Ex - ?-inconcat(maggy,girl,A).
 A = mg.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming X and Y are the two words you wish to use, and Z is the output, I think we first need to start by validating both words, and not just X. Next, your name()s split up each word into three different variables, when we are only interested in the first letter of each word.

Remember that name() takes in an atom and a list, as shown in the documentation, as so:

```
name(Atom,List).
```

This will take a single atom and turn it into a list of ASCII codes, as so:

```
?- name(abc,A).
A = "abc"
```

From there, we can extract the head of the list using the familiar [A|B] format for lists, as so:

```
?- name(abc,[A|B]).
B = "bc"
A = 97
```

As shown above, 97 is the ASCII code for 'a'. This also works in reverse. Having a variable for the Atom and a list of ASCII codes for the List, you can (essentially) concatenate strings, as so:

```
?- name(A,[97,98,99]).
A = abc
```

Knowing all of that, and doing everything twice, that will lead us to:

```
?- abc = X, def = Y, name(X,[A|C]), name(Y,[B|D]), name(Z,[A,B]).
Z = ad,
D = "ef",
B = 100,
C = "bc",
A = 97,
Y = def,
X = abc
```

Circling back to your case, we have as so:

```
?- maggie = X, girl = Y, name(X,[A|C]), name(Y,[B|D]), name(Z,[A,B]).
Z = mg,
D = "irl",
B = 103,
C = "aggie",
A = 109,
Y = girl,
X = maggie
```

Comment: @ela For many reasons (I can go into it if you feel like you need to know), it is better to use more standard predicates. The same can be done using `sub_atom/5` and `atom_chars/2`: `?- sub_atom(maggie, 0, 1, _, A), sub_atom(girl, 0, 1, _, B), atom_chars(R, [A,B]).`